# Limit of a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let us consider $f\in {L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}$ such that there exists the weak derivative $\partial_{x_1}(|f|^2)\in {L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}$, can we ensure that $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\partial_{x_1}(|f|^2)=0$?

I know that there is a version of Fundamental Calculus Theorem for weak derivative which says that (fixing $x_2,\dots,x_N$) we can find a continuous function, $\bar{f}$, such that  $\bar{f}=|f|^2$ a.e. and $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\partial_{x_1}(|f|^2)=\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N-1}} \left(\lim_{x_1\to+\infty} \bar f-\lim_{x_1\to-\infty} \bar f\right)$. So, the proof will be complete if I prove that$\displaystyle\lim_{x_1\to\pm\infty} \bar f=0$.

Could someone help me with this last step?

Comment: Why $\int \partial _1(|f|^2)=0$ ?

Comment: It's only intuition (which  is usually wrong). Do you know an example of function in $L^2$ for which $lim_{x\to\infty}|f|^2\neq{0}$?

Comment: @Loye94 Take a sequence of bump functions $f_{n}$ with support of volume $1/n^2$ and height $1$